# How to pass parameters on POST requests on Spring-MVC controller method

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC.

I am sending a POST request from an Ajax context and I sent one parameter. The Content-Type of the request is `{'Content-Type':'application/json;'}` and in Firefox's Firebug I see the post request is sent with one parameter:

```
JSON
orderId "1"

Source
{"orderId":"1"}
```

How can I get it in my controller in the server? The signature of my method is:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/blahblah", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void blahblah(@RequestBody(required=false) String orderId ){...
```

The incoming orderId is always null. Any ideas?

Thanks..

UPDATED: I used {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'} and send my parameters in the following format "orderId=" + id . Also, I changed the server method using @RequestParam String orderId and the value is passed.

Comment: what does your web server log say ? Are you sure the requestmapping is correct

Comment: Yes, the requestmapping is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'}` and send my parameters in the following format "orderId=" + id .

I changed also the server method using `@RequestParam String orderId` and the value is passed.